# Why can’t a lady blow Shofar for a man?

Tags: halacha, women, shofar

If the Mitzvah is to hear the sound of the Shofar - not to blow it - then why can’t a man fulfill his obligation by hearing from a lady’s blowing, if the דין שומע כעונה doesn’t apply here?

Comment: It's a time bound positive command. Meritorious as it may be for them to endeavor to blow or hear it, women are not technically obligated in it. In order for shome'a k'oneh to work, the blower must have a greater or equal degree of obligation to the listener. Women do not have the same obligation as men, therefore a man cannot fulfill the miswah by hearing it from a woman.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Does shomea keoneh make it like I screamed the shofar blast? What's the "keoneh" of which you speak?

Comment: Even better ask about a goy. Or a monkey.

Comment: A woman can't be motzi because כל שאינו מחוייב בדבר אינו מוציא אחרים ידי חובתן. But if your question is that it's purely about hearing a sound and there's no need for the blower to be motzi, then it's no different from a goy.

Comment: @DoubleAA the action of the שמיעה is considered to be like the ענייה. If I recall, there's a Reb Haim on this, but it's been a while.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I don't know what "the action of the שמיעה is considered to be like the ענייה" means, and more importantly, why an ענייה is relevant. The mitzva is hearing. Why are you using some axiom to transform his hearing into something else?

Comment: @DoubleAA your last question indicates that you do know what it means. As for relevance, OP mentions the principle in this context as do several Aharonim. As for "transforming" - it isn't a transformation, it is a legal principle that some Aharonim have found useful in analyzing the mechanics of this miswah. Some agree with the application some find it altogether misplaced (as apparently you do). If you insist on some citations I can try to dig them up later (let me know), but I don't think we need to engage in extended discussion about it here in the comments.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I suppose it's not that simple, because women took upon themselves the commandment of hearing the שופר, and now they are obligated in it, like hearing פרשת זכור. But I do not know whether based on this choice they could exempt others or not. A good answer should discuss this intermediate category from this perspective.

Comment: There is a really wonderful Hegyonei Halacha (Rabbi Mirsky) which deals at length with the topic of who is yotzei with what and by whom, etc.

Comment: @Kazibácsi those women that have accepted it upon themselves do so by force of minhag/neder. It is not incumbent upon them directly as a Torah obligation as it is for a man.

Comment: And as far I understand women hear Parshas Zachor because according to some opinions they are obligated to.

Answer (score 3):

The [Levush 589:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14585&st=&pgnum=211) explains that although in theory any sound should suffice, even from a monkey (or a machine??), however Chazal qualified that it must be a sound that is made by someone who is chayiv in the mitzvah

The Har Tzvi (R’ Tzvi Pesach Frank) is said to of explained that someone who isn’t chayiv is just playing a flute, not blowing shofar for the mitzvah, and such a sound isn’t what the Torah required for the mitzvah.

Based on this, some say a woman shouldn’t even blow for a woman since the second woman will not be hearing a sound of the shofar of mitzvah.

Comment: *Chazal qualified*... are you saying the requirement is rabbinic? *some say a woman shouldn’t even blow for a woman*... What about for herself?

Comment: No. I’m saying that chazal qualified that the definition of the mitzvah is only under certain circumstances. Blowing for herself is permitted by Shulchan Aruch 589

Comment: Why would blowing for herself be better than for another woman?

Comment: Good point. I would imagine because then she’s yotzei by blowing not hearing, so for her it’s ok. But that’s just my svara

Comment: See also Rav Moshe Shternbuch's piece on this in Moadim UZmanim

Comment: @robev, would you mind sending a link or summarizing what he says